# What details do I need to GET data from elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

My team has data stored on ElasticSearch and have given me an API key, the URL of a remote cluster, and a username/password combination (to what I dont know) to GET data.

How do I use this API key to get data from the ElasticSearch cluster with Python? I've looked through the docs, but none include the use of a raw API key and most involve localhost, not a remote host in my case.

Surely I need to know the names of nodes or indexes at least? For what would I need the username/password combo for? There must be more details I need to connect with than what I've been given?

We're moving from Node.js+couchbase work to ElasticSearch+Python so I'm more than a bit lost.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Most probably x-pack basic security is enabled in your Elasticsearch(ES) cluster, which you can check by hitting http::9200, if it ask for username/password then you can provide what you have.

Please refer [x-pack page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html) for more info.

In short, its used to secure your cluster and indices and there are various types of authentication and basic auth(which requires username/password) is the one your team might be using.